# Palindromo sin utilizar métodos predefinidos del lenguaje (como Reverse() o Replace()) en PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php
  $array = array (0, 1, 2, 3);
  echo 'numeros son son <br>';
  for($i = 0; $i <=4; $i++) {
    unset($array[$i]);
    print_r($array);
  };
?>
```

Necesito ayuda no puedo hacerlo sin metodos

Comment: por favor lee [ask] la comunidad te ayudará con gusto pero es necesario muestres lo que llevas; de otro modo parece que piedes se te haga la tarea

Comment: Porque todos creen que es tarea, es curiosidad y si he hecho cmoo diez codigos pero usando metodos, sin metodos no me imagino nada necesito verlo

Comment: aunque no sea tarea, aqui no les hacemos los códigos a los demás; muestra que llevas

Comment: <?php
$palindromo = "somos";
$conversion = "somos";
if(palindromo==conversion){
 echo'no es un palindromo';
}
else{
 echo'si es un palindromo';
}
?>

Comment: <?php
$array array('s''o''m''o''s');
for(array=4; array<=0; array++){
 echo(array);
?>

Comment: `<?php
  $array = array (0, 1, 2, 3);
  echo 'numeros son son <br>';
  for($i = 0; $i <=4; $i++) {
    unset($array[$i]);
    print_r($array);
  };
?>`

Comment: click en [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/213850/edit) y podes agregar todas las variantes con comentarios de por qué no te funciona

Answer (score 0):

Una posibilidad es recorrer la mitad del String e ir comprobando la primera con la última, la segunda con la penultima, etc.

Eso sería algo así:

```html
<?php
  //Se crea un array de los string que necesites
  $array = ["somos", "son"];
 
  //Recorremos las palabras del array
  for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    $palindromo = true;
    echo "Palabra : " . $array[$i] . "\n";

    //Asigno la palabra del array a la variable $palabra
    $palabra = $array[$i];

    //Se recorren todos los string de la palabra
    for($j = 0; $j < (strlen($palabra)/2); $j++) {
       //En caso de que sea false se detiene el for
       if($palindromo === false){
         $j = strlen($palabra)/2;
       }
       //Hacemos la comprobación como explico arriba y si no son iguales, se pone en false
       else if($palabra[$j] !== $palabra[(strlen($palabra)-1) - $j])
       {
         $palindromo = false;
       }
    }
    //Imprimimos resultado dependiendo de lo que salga
    if($palindromo === false){
      echo "La palabra " . $array[$i] . " no es un palindromo" . "\n";
    }
    else{
      echo "La palabra " . $array[$i] . " si es un palindromo" . "\n";
    }
  }

?>
```

De igual manera puedes ahcerlo con los números, sólo tienes que recorrer el array hasta la mitad y mirar que coincidan.